# How can i get the numerical value (convert it to int) from a string?

Tags: c, string, type-conversion

I only see strings with only numbers. this is my string.
SMUL 9 A B
How can I get the number 9 as int type. Other possible string may be:
SMUL 13 A B
SMUL 43 100 21

Comment: So `SMUL 9 A B` would give you back `9`. What would `SMUL 13 A B SMUL 43 100 21` result into?

Comment: oh sorry. i forgot to separate them. SMUL 13 A B --> gives me back 13. SMUL 43 100 21 gives me back the three numbers. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

try your luck with [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `atoi` library function:

```
   int atoi(const char *nptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

atoi is bad, there is no error-handling, eg: atoi("0")==atoi("foobar") !
use strtol or sscanf instead.